# Division by zero ErrorException in Table.php line 173: in laravel dompdf converter

Tags: laravel, dompdf

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" style="max-width:700px;background:white;padding: 10px;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: brown;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;">Walkover Web Solutions Private Limited</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I am getting the division by zero error while converting this html to pdf by dompdf. May I know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: it said Table.php line 173.. have you check on that line??

Comment: Your question appears to have been cut off

Comment: `if ($absolute_used == 0 && $percent_used == 0) {
                $increment = $width - $min_width;

                foreach (array_keys($columns) as $i) {
                    $cellmap->set_column_width($i, $columns[$i]["min-width"] + $increment * ($columns[$i]["max-width"] / $max_width));
                }
                return;
            }`
There this code is been there seem css calculation is been done there

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic i have searched for this issue but it doesnt seems any solutions

Comment: @BrijeshDhanani I mean your questions says "May I know what I a..." and does not finish

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic i was asking what i am doing wrong here?. Looks like question got cut off

Answer (score 3):

got the fix where it was causing problem. Looks like it this dompdf don't accept the `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` in table styling. After removing the this from the style of table it worked fine. Even though design was not upto the mark but still this error got resolved

Answer (score 1):

Each (open td) and (closed td) must write in different line instead of same line.

Example:

```
<td>
This is correct way.
</td>

<td>This is wrong way</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute width="100%" for the tables. doing this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I update `laravel-dompdf` package

> v1.1.1 => v1.2.0

I face this error

> Division by zero

after Debugging I found that you can not use `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` together with `width: 100%;`

#### Incorrect Way:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
```

#### Correct Way:

```
<table width="100%">
</table>
```

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
</table>
```

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
```

> Note: **Your CSS Styling may effect**